# Can you peek at your cards from future years in Seasons?

Tags: seasons

In Seasons, after you have selected cards for all 3 years, can you take a look at cards from future years to plan which energy to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the rulebook section II - Constructing your deck:

> From the nine power cards chosen, each player should assemble three
> sets  of three cards each. The first set immediately forms the
> player’s hand, as it  corresponds to the cards with which the players
> will begin their tournament.
>
> The second set is placed under the
> Library II token and will be added to  the player’s hand during the
> second year of  the tournament. As for the third set of power  cards,
> it is placed under the Library III token  and will be added to the
> player’s hand during  the third and final year of the tournament. **At
> any point during the game, players can look  at the power cards
> they’ve selected.**

Emphasis mine.  Assuming I've understood your question correctly, there is no bar to looking at your cards for year two and year three to remind yourself what they are.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's a bug in the BGA implementation.  Then again, it's still in beta over there.